# The link does not open in server but works in local

Tags: php, hyperlink, server, connection, local

I tried this in local and it shows $arr[0]:

```
    try{
    $file= "http://IP:8030/app_dev.php/api/v1/get_jhoobin_users";
    $csv= file_get_contents($file);
    $array = array_map("str_getcsv", explode("\n", $csv));
    foreach ($array as $arr){
        echo $arr[0]."<br>";
    }
} catch(Exception $e) {
    $error = $e->getMessage();
    echo $error;
}
```

but in server my error is:
 file_get_contents(http://IP:8030/app_dev.php/api/v1/get_jhoobin_users): failed to open stream: Connection timed out in /var/www/html/SDP/other/microchargeNew40.php

Comment: The URL you are giving in file is your local server URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked after changing port.